# Resteasy (multipart/form-data): how to read multi value field values to List?

Tags: java, resteasy

I need a little help with resteasy.
I have a multipart web form with some multi-value fields. 
My request data for topics parameter:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary2sX84QQsaESs9qTv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="topics"

3569
------WebKitFormBoundary2sX84QQsaESs9qTv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="topics"

18421
------WebKitFormBoundary2sX84QQsaESs9qTv
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="topics"

9703
```

How can I read "topics" parameter to list ? 
This is how my property for topics parameter is annotated

```
@FormParam("topics")
private String[]  topics;
```

but I get an exception:

```
Unable to find a MessageBodyReader for media type: text/plain;charset="us-ascii" and class type [Ljava.lang.String;
```

Any help or example would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

Armando

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
@PUT
@Path("/someurl")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
@Produces("text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public String someUrl(MultipartFormDataInput form) 
{
    try {
        List<InputPart> l = form.getFormDataMap().get("topics");
        String topic1 = l.get(0).getBodyAsString();
        String topic2 = l.get(1).getBodyAsString();
        String topic3 = l.get(2).getBodyAsString();
        // do something with the topics ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "something went wrong";
}
```

Comment: I manage to get the data as you suggested but the String is not corrected encoded. For example, I got this "Invent��rio" instead of this "Inventário". Any ideas? Tks